Invalid content was found starting with element 'class'. No child element is expected at this point
I'm encountering this strange error on the class keywords in this code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasehoi"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="hoihoi"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Password1!"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
        <class>com.han.labonderzoek.entities.Owners</class>
        <class>com.han.labonderzoek.entities.Playlists</class>
        <class>com.han.labonderzoek.entities.PlaylistsTracks</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

the error moves away when i put the class lines before the properties, but then it starts crying the javax.persistence.jdbc.url needs to be defined, so i feel like that's the wrong order.
I'm using a jakarta ee app with jpa, hibernate and mysql.
